# How to set a Resource picture as a background?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background

I'm trying to set a backgroundpicture for my button in my code behind. The picture is available as a png in the resources.

```
Button sampleBody = new Button();
ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush((ImageSource)Properties.Resources.MyPic);
imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

sampleBody.Background = imageBrush;
```

The above code isn't working (obviously) but that's what I'm trying todo in a nutshell.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Button Content property can be used to display an image,

Comment: WPF uses image resources in a different way. Do not add an image to Resources.resx. Instead, just add an image file to the Visual Studio project and load it via a Resource File Pack URI: `new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/mypic.png")));`

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the answer. The real question is that I have a bitmap class property that I want to use as a backgroundimage. I wanted to use resources just for testing. So I need a way to do this without URIs.

Comment: While this is not the typical way to use an image resource in WPF, you may of course just convert from Bitmap to ImageSource. Just search StackOverflow, there are a couple of solutions. Either encode the Bitmap to a MemoryStream, from which you decode a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame, or use `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap`.

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement this. Because you said this isn't a typical way to use image resources in WPF: My app has various diffrent components which all have a different image. The user can create new elements and load them as an extension into the program.  How could this work if I want to manage all components in an internal list? Do you have a tipp for me?

Comment: An assembly resource file shouldn't be handled any different than a bitmap resource in Resources.resx. It is located in an assembly, but can be accessed from other assemblies. Pack URIs can contain referenced assembly names: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris

Comment: Kay, thx :)

`Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` also worked perfectly.